# Convert $r=1+2\cos(2\theta)$ to Cartesian

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I want to convert $r=1+2\cos 2\theta$ to  Cartesian.

$r=1+2(\cos^2\theta  -\sin^2\theta)$

$r=1+2\left(\dfrac{x^2}{r^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{r^2}\right) \iff
\dfrac{r-1}{2}=\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

$r$ won't go away.

$(r-1)^2=r^2-2r+1$

No matter how I do it, the $r$ stays.
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: r = 1 + 2cos(2theta)

Comment: r = 1 +2(cos^2(theta)-sin^2(theta))

Comment: r = 1 +2((x^2/r^2)-(y^2/r^2))

Comment: (r-1)/2 = (x^2 -y^2) / (x^2 + y^2)

Comment: if (r-1)^2 = r^2-2r +1. so r stays.

Comment: $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so in the worst case you can use that to get rid of $r$.

Answer (score 1):

$x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$

Given curve $\, r = 1 + 2 \cos 2\theta = 4 \cos^2 \theta - 1$

$\implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{4x^2}{x^2+y^2} - 1$

$\implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{3x^2 - y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

$\implies (x^2+y^2)^3 = (3x^2 - y^2)^2$